# How to prove a function is not differentiable

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

Given:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 &&&  x<2  \\x+6 && &x \geq 2 \end{cases} $$

I need to prove that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=2$, what should I do?
$$\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{f(x) -f(2)}{x-2} =\lim_{x \to 2^+}  \frac{x+6-8}{x-2} = 1  $$
$$\lim_{x \to 2^-} \frac{f(x) -f(2)}{x-2}  =\lim_{x \to 2^+}  \frac{x^3 -8}{x-2} = 6  $$
Is taking limits for the two functions and showing that those two are not equal correct?

Comment: Yes, just fix the $2^+$ on the right hand side of the second equation (should be $2^-$).

Comment: Could you, please, verify the result of 6?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the alternative, which is take the symbolic derivative of $f(x)$. The result is:

\begin{align}
f'(x) = 3x^2 & , 1 \\
f'(2) = 12 & , 1
\end{align} and $12 \neq 1$.

Comment: I hope you find my edit correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. I don't remember what I had mistyped, maybe it was just for clarity that you changed stuff?

Comment: Yes, just for clarity ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of continuity: $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$. Clearly $\lim_{x \to 2^{-}}3 x^2 = 12 \neq 1 = f(2)$.